# Excel bugs in formula

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, formula, ifs

I can't use the IFS formula in EXCEL.

The formula is?

```
=SES(X2>=Concluído;Concluído;X2>=Concluído/Em Validação Controles;Concluído/Em Validação Controles;X2>=Concluído/Em Validação Rev. Independente;Concluído/Em Validação Rev. Independente;X2>=Em Andamento (Responsável);Em Validação;X2>=Em Validação Revisor;Em Validação)
```

But, my result is #NAME?

Can anybody help me?

I tried to use the "if formula" in excel and it return some "X" value, but this not happened

Comment: What are the values you are comparing X2 to? If they are words, they should be in quotation marks.

Comment: It worked but the outputs all appear as "completed" but they should have varied responses.

My new formula is: =SES(X3>="Concluído";"Concluído";X3>="Concluído/Em Validação Controles";"Concluído/Em Validação Controles";X3>="Concluído/Em Validação Rev. Independente";"Concluído/Em Validação Rev. Independente";X3>="Em Andamento (Responsável)";"Em Validação";X3>="Em Validação Revisor";"Em Validação")

Comment: I suspect you just want `=` rather than `>=` since alphabetically all of those values are greater than the first one.